Added variable plot and CCPR plot for categorical variable
Do the added variable plot and the CCPR plot make sense for categorical variables? The significance of the variable can be obtained from the partial F-test, and non-linearity only applies to continuous variables.
And CCPR plot for an interaction effect with a categorical and a continuous predictor (for one level of the categorical variable represented by 0, all points have x-coordinate equal to 0)?
Thank you very much.
